# sum all the values inside javascript loop using reduce method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping cart.html page where user selected items displays in a table. I want to show Grand Total of all totals in each row of the table. My code are as follows-

```
function showCart() {
        if (cart.length == 0) {
            $("#cart").css("visibility", "hidden");
            return;
        }

        $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#cartBody").empty();
        for (var i in cart) {
            var item = cart[i];
            var total = item.Qty * item.Price + item.Chrg;
            var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
                         item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>"
                         + item.Chrg + "</td><td>"
                         + total + "</td><td>"
                         + "<button onclick='deleteItem(" + i + ")'>Delete</button></td></tr>";

            $("#cartBody").append(row);

        }
    }
```

HTML

```
            <table id="cart" border="1" style="visibility:hidden; width:100%">
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Product</th>
                          <th>Price</th>
                          <th>Qty</th>
                          <th>Del. Charge</th>
                          <th>Total</th>
                          <th></th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody id="cartBody">

                 </tbody>
            </table>
```

RESULT
I get this -

```
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Product |Price | Qty | Del.Charge | Total |
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Chips   | 20   |  5  |  10        | 110   |
| Coke    | 50   |  3  |  10        | 160   |
| Corn    | 10   |  2  |  10        |  30   |
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

Now I want to show Grand Total at bottom of the table, like this:

```
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Product |Price | Qty | Del.Charge | Total |
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Chips   | 20   |  5  |  10        | 110   |
| Coke    | 50   |  3  |  10        | 160   |
| Corn    | 10   |  2  |  10        |  30   |
+---------+------+-----+------------+-------+
Grand Total: 200
```

So far I tried this

```
var gtotal = new Array; //placed above for loop

gtotal = total + ',';
console.log(gtotal); //shows 110,160,30,

var gtotal = [gtotal].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
$("#gtotal").append(gtotal); //append result on div id gtotal on cart.html page
```

This displays - 0110,0160,030, //it is prefixing 0

Comment: `gtotal = total + ','; [gtotal].reduce...` No matter what, you'd be iterating over an array with a single value, a string...

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you suggest me how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
gtotal = total + ',';
console.log(gtotal); //shows 110,160,30,

var gtotal = [gtotal].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
$("#gtotal").append(gtotal); //append result on div id gtotal on cart.html page
```

> This displays - 0110,0160,030, //it is prefixing 0

That is because you are doing `a+b` in your reducing function with 0 as accumulator. Since you are using `[gtotal]` as input array, there is only one reduce step: with `110,0160,030,`. Then `a+b` is done. With your 0 as accumulator, adding `0` to a string just leads to that behavior because the + operator here is a concatenation operation.

I have used `.split(',')` to turn your comma separate string in an array of numeric elements as String (so `gtotal.split(',')` gives `["110", "160", "30", ""]`). Then I used `.map` to convert these string values to a Number type. At last, `.reduce` can be used to get your total value.

```js
var gtotal = '110,160,30,';
console.log(gtotal); //shows 110,160,30,

var totalValue = gtotal.split(',').map(s => Number(s)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(totalValue);
```

PS: you can shorten `.map(s => Number(s))` into `.map(Number)` if you want.

Comment: You shouldn't map just to parse to a number. Instead use `reduce((a,b)=>a+Number(b), 0)`

Comment: @bambam sure, you can do that either. It is just a habit of mine that if a reduce returns with a number, ensure that the input array is a number. that gives you an advantage on readability + maintainability (eg want to use a custom function or doing some additional manipulation required? then just adjust the map function)

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of performance. Two loops vs. one. That's a huge performance impact on large arrays

Comment: @CertainPerformance You probably missed the post scriptum. That happens.